# Gutenberg block throwing error after upgrade from 3.6.2 to 3.7.0

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I created a block which pulls content from a CPT. I had no errors and everything worked correctly within the Gutenberg editor until I upgraded from Gutenberg 3.6.2 to 3.7.0. I went through the 3.7.0 changelog and nothing looked questionable at first glance.

**Error thrown in console:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined
```

**Relevant code:**

```
// Create model and collection for custom post type.
var SwiftModule = wp.api.models.Post.extend({
    urlRoot: wpApiSettings.root + wpApiSettings.versionString + 'modules',
    defaults: {
        type: 'modules'
    }
});
var SwiftModules = wp.api.collections.Posts.extend({
    url: wpApiSettings.root + wpApiSettings.versionString + 'modules',
    model: SwiftModule
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that 'wp-api' is no longer enqueued in versions > 3.6.2 of the Gutenberg plugin. Everything is working nicely again after running `wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-api' );` in my own code.